# Перевод из десятичной дроби в цепную

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика

Как можно на C++ перевести представленное в виде десятичной дроби число в [непрерывную (цепную)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C) дробь?

Comment: Пример того и другого можно?

Comment: @sanmai 1,25= 1+ 1/4

Comment: То есть известно заранее что число точно можно превратить?

Comment: Опишите проблему конкретнее, что не получилось? Приведите пример  кода. Пока ваш вопрос выглядит, как задание.

Comment: Что такое непрерывная дробь?

Comment: @IntFloat я не могу понять реализацию

Comment: Это вам не к нам, об алгоритме спрашивайте у математиков.

Comment: @pishak Вам бы надо было добавить к вопросу теги "алгоритм" и "математика"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рекурсивно-итеративно, как больше нравится :) - выделение целой части + `1/x`. Другое дело, что после определенного количества шагов о точности можно будет позабыть.

Мне бы не хотелось писать за вас код, это непедагогично :)
Поэтому просто несколько шагов вручную для pi:

```
3 + 0.1415925... = 3 + 1/(7+0.0625133...) = 3 + 1/(7 + 1/(15+0.996...)
```

и так далее.

Comment: Довольно часто стоит задача восстановить исходную дробь -  скажем, 17/7. И желательно без дополнительной ручной работы.

Answer (score 2):

Для решения таких задач было бы полезно ознакомиться с представлением чисел с плавающей точкой.

Можно предложить такой алгоритм.

1. Разделяем число на целую и дробную части (например, функцией `modf`).
2. Получаем числитель и знаменатель умножая оставшуюся дробную часть на `FLT_RADIX` пока она не станет равна нулю.

Comment: Вы путаете "обыкновенную дробь" и "непрерывную дробь" - это разные вещи (и, кстати, исправление вопроса выполнено напрасно - вопрос стал совершенно иным). См. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C

Answer (score 2):

Непрерывную дробь строят при помощи алгоритма Евклида:
**x = [q<sub>0</sub>, q<sub>1</sub>, q<sub>2</sub>...  ]**, где

**q<sub>0</sub> = [x], r<sub>0</sub> = x - q<sub>0</sub>,**
**q<sub>s+1</sub> = [1 / r<sub>s</sub>], r<sub>s+1</sub> = 1/r<sub>s</sub> - q<sub>s+1</sub>, 
s=0, 1,...**

Подходящие дроби (приближения числа **x** вида **P<sub>s</sub> / Q<sub>s</sub>**) вычисляют по формулам:
**P<sub>0</sub> = 1, Q<sub>0</sub> = 0**
**P<sub>1</sub> = q<sub>0</sub>, Q<sub>1</sub> = 1**
**P<sub>s+1</sub> = q<sub>s+1</sub>P<sub>s</sub> + P<sub>s-1</sub>,

Q<sub>s+1</sub> = q<sub>s+1</sub>Q<sub>s</sub> + Q<sub>s-1</sub>,

s = 1, 2, ...**

По логике непрерывных дробей (компактные приближения числа **x**) этот процесс не должен быть бесконечным. Поэтому вычисления следует обрывать не только при нулевой дробной части, но и при достижении заданной точности.

Программа на PHP выглядит так:

```
function print_e($text, $entier){
    print $text."[";
    foreach($entier as $key => $ent){
        if($key) print ", ";
        print $ent;
    }
    print "]";
}

function print_c($text, $num, $denom){
    print $text;
    $first = true;
    array_map(function($n, $d) use(&$first){
        if(!$first) print "&emsp;";
        print "$n/$d";
        $first = false;         
    }, $num, $denom);
}; 

function float_to_ratio($x, $epsilon = 1e-7, $ent = []){
    $numerator[] = 1;
    $denominator[] = 0;
    $ent[0] = floor($x);
    $frac = $x - $ent[0];
    $numerator[] = $ent[0];
    $denominator[] = 1;
    while((abs($x - end($numerator)/end($denominator)) > $epsilon)
    && ($frac > 0)){
        $verse = 1/$frac; 
        $ent[] = floor($verse);
        $frac = $verse - end($ent);
        $numerator[] = end($ent)*current($numerator) + prev($numerator);
        $denominator[] = end($ent)*current($denominator) + prev($denominator);
    };
    print_e("* x = $x&emsp;epsilon = $epsilon<br>* continued fraction: ", $ent);
    print_c("<br>* convergents: ", $numerator, $denominator);
    return [end($numerator), end($denominator)];
}

$ratio = float_to_ratio($x = 17/7);
print "<br>&emsp;$x = {$ratio[0]}/{$ratio[1]}<br><br>";

$ratio = float_to_ratio($x = 5.333);
print "<br>&emsp;$x = {$ratio[0]}/{$ratio[1]}<br><br>";

$ratio = float_to_ratio($x = 5.333, 1e-3);
print "<br>&emsp;$x = {$ratio[0]}/{$ratio[1]}";
```

Результаты:

```
* x = 2.42857142857 epsilon = 1.0E-7
* continued fraction: [2, 2, 2, 1]
* convergents: 1/0 2/1 5/2 12/5 17/7
 2.42857142857 = 17/7

* x = 5.333 epsilon = 1.0E-7
* continued fraction: [5, 3, 333]
* convergents: 1/0 5/1 16/3 5333/1000
 5.333 = 5333/1000

* x = 5.333 epsilon = 0.001
* continued fraction: [5, 3]
* convergents: 1/0 5/1 16/3
 5.333 = 16/3
```